# Where in Pokemon X can I find that character that won't let me pass because I wasn't a champion?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

While I playing Pokemon X in the earlier moments, I came across this character that won't let me enter because I wasn't a champion yet. Now that I have defeated the Pokemon Leauge Champion I wish to find that character, but the problem is that I don't remember where he is.

Comment: There are at least two that I know of; one in Terminus Cave, and one in Pokemon Village.

Comment: I think I know what you are talking about. I'm drawing a blank on the town name but it's right before Lumiose City. The town has a little area you can access in the top-right of the town. Follow that path and you enter the area with the League (if I remember correctly). One person tell you to get 8 badges before you enter (he blocks the path going up) and another person just to the right of him says you need to be more powerful to pass. I'm not terribly knowledgeable on this stuff, but is that the part you are talking about? I only remember because I found that part myself.

Comment: @LinkofOrigin No, that's the start of Victory Road.  You don't become champion until after that part, so I don't think that's it.

Comment: @fbueckert Oh ok, nevermind then. I've only got about 2 badges worth of Pokemon X knowledge right now, but I thought that might be it :P

Comment: I think it's most probably Pokemon Village (in front of the entrance of a cave accessible after using Surf and in front of which there's a ledge) since the player is forced to go there. Terminus Cave is a bit harder to get around and some people might get discouraged by the long winded path to the depths of this cave.

Answer (score 2):

There are two areas that are not accessible when you are not champion.  These are Terminus Cave, which holds legendary Pokemon, #718 Zygarde, and Pokemon Village, where #150 Mewtwo. To get to Mewtwo's Unknown Dungeon, you will need to have Surf.  These two Pokemon are level 70.  If it's not any of the two, then it might be the Lost Hotel, where a man also blocks you from passing, but you don't need to be champion for this, you only need to learn the roller skate tricks.

Comment: The Lost Hotel does not require that you become the champion. You just need to have found and used all 4 roller skating tricks.

Comment: @Reafexus I know that, maybe the person who asked didn't know about the cycle tricks and thought he could only pass when he's champion.

Comment: Ah ok. I got sidetracked on the actual goal of the question.